# Trying to use angular ngTable in a class-like javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, ngtable

I am trying to use ngTable in my project, we wrap js logic class-like (actually this gets translated from coffescript but I am working with the generated js), the source looks like this https://gist.github.com/orlybg/1531df6684f814f9a6f0.

I am trying to adapt http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3 to my project.

The table itself gets generated/drawn, what I am trying to do know is do asc/desc sorting of the data when the headers are clicked. I dont even need pagination.

```
this.$scope.tableParams = new this.ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        name: 'id'     // initial sorting
    }
}, {
total: this.pools.length, // length of data
    getData: this.getData(this.$q, params)
});
```

The latest error I'm getting after lots of tweaking is: ReferenceError: params is not defined
from the code snippet above, so I am wondering where ngTable params comes from and how I can get and pass it to my this to MyController.prototype.getData = function($defer, params).

What do you guys thing of the approach, is it even possible, or I am way off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the getData property to the result of a function, rather than to the function itself.

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
    return ...
}
```

Depending on your familiarity with javascript, out might think to do

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {
    return this.getData(this.$q, params);
}
```

But this will not work, because JavaScript throws away `this` inside function declarations. You can either do

```
getData: this.getData.bind(this);
```

Which might not work with older browsers, or you can do

```
var that = this;
```

before you start creating the params, and then do

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {
    return that.getData(that.$q, params);
}
```

Although I'm not sure why you are using this.$q since the example you referred to doesn't use any async operations. You should use the $defer argument instead of this.$q and then call $defer.resolve(yourData) at the end of your function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the 'that = this' approach, also I changed $q for $defer, one more thing I had to change was in the template I was not using $data but my own variable, that's why nothing ever happened, but well it is sorting now, next is to see what else can ngTable do for me, thanks again!